# ASP.NET and Oracle Stored Procedure Error

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am VERY new when it comes to stored procedures and .NET, so I apologize in advance. I have a stored procedure that I am trying to use and I keep getting this error..."wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'COPY_ACCOUNT'". I am not sure why. Below is my stored procedure code followed by my C#.NET code. Any help is GREATLY appreciated. PLEASE.

```
create or replace procedure abstract_names.copy_account(r_rows_copied out int,
                                                    ar_old_acct in  abn_headings.acct_no%type,
                                                    ar_new_acct in  abn_headings.acct_no%type)
is  
cnt int := 0;
begin
    r_rows_copied := 0;
 for r in (select heading from abn_headings where acct_no = ar_old_acct) loop      
  copy_heading(cnt, ar_old_acct, r.heading, ar_new_acct);
  r_rows_copied := r_rows_copied + cnt; 
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line('called abstract_names.copy_account '||to_char(r_rows_copied));   
return; end;
```

Then my C#.NET code...

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
try
{
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

    cmd.Parameters.Add("r_rows_copied", OracleType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ar_from_acct", OracleType.VarChar).Value = accountNumberDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ar_to_acct", OracleType.VarChar).Value = copyAccountDDL.SelectedValue.ToString();
    cmd = new OracleCommand("abstract_names.copy_account", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    /*
    abstract_names.copy_account(r_rows_copied out int,
                        ar_from_acct in  abn_headings.acct_no%type,
                        ar_to_acct in  abn_headings.acct_no%type)
    */
}
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
        conn.Close();
}
```

My connection string is correct because I use it else where in my code and it works. The commented section is the stored procedure i am trying to use obviously. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at your code and not being familiar with this OracleCommand object, it looks like you're creating parameters and then creating a new object in the middle wiping out all your parameter additions.  Create a new object from the connection and then add your parameters.  Attempting a stab at better code below.  Also I would use using statements for any conneciton,commnand objects to ensure they get closed and disposed.

Edit: Didn't look too deep, my fault.  It looks like the parameter names weren't matching up in the stored procedure and the .net code.  Also since you're returning a value, I would use the ExecuteScalar method, ExeuteNonQuery won't return any data.

```
cmd = new OracleCommand("abstract_names.copy_account", conn);                      
cmd.Parameters.Add("r_rows_copied", OracleType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ar_old_acct ", OracleType.VarChar).Value = accountNumberDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("ar_new_acct", OracleType.VarChar).Value = copyAccountDDL.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the code above and I am still getting the same error. Any other ideas? I am completely lost on this one.

Comment: I should have looked a bit closer, it looks like the parameter names weren't matching up in the stored procedure and .net code. The names of course need to be exactly the same.  It also looks like you're returning a value so you should use ExecuteScalar as ExecuteNonQuery won't let you get any data back.  If you're not returning that out parameter ExecuteNonQuery is fine.

Comment: What parameter names weren't matching up? I removed the out in the stored procedure because i only want the procedure to update the table, i do not need anything returned.

Comment: Ok, just make sure the input parameter names match up in the SP and the .net code.  And since you're not returning data using the ExecuteNonQuery method is fine.  I would remove the output parameter from the command object then.

Comment: I removed it from the SP and the code and am using ExecuteNonQuery() now. Could it possibly be that the "ar_old_acct in  abn_headings.acct_no%type" part of my SP is a VarChar2 and I am passing in a listItem.ToString()? I am out of ideas.

Comment: As long as the parameter names match up and the data types match up it should work.  Can you edit the SP and .net code to reflect any changes you've made?

Answer (score 0):

You assign a new instance to your `cmd` variable, then you lose reference to what you had done.

Here:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ar_to_acct", OracleType.VarChar).Value = copyAccountDDL.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd = new OracleCommand("abstract_names.copy_account", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

This is the wrong line:

```
cmd = new OracleCommand("abstract_names.copy_account", conn);
```

Just by looking at your code, I think you should simply remove that line and it should be OK.

Comment: If i remove that line completely, then it will not know what procedure i am referencing. I tried it however and I get an error stating that the connection is closed. Any other advice? I am completely lost here as to why this will not work.